# Null Values in Zones in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have graphs that have zones. Currently if there is a null value, that null value is displayed in the tooltip with the zone color of the point before it. I want the null value to always be the color black.

For example, 
[image: Zones]

The tooltip in graph 1 has all the correct information... but "Strength: null" has a green dot. I want to make this dot black because it is a null value.

Is it possible to make this happen? Thanks so much.

https://codepen.io/austeng/pen/gOppRWY

```
zones: [
  {
    value: 0.3,
    color: "green"
  },
  {
    value: 0.5,
    color: "black",
  },
  {
    color: "red"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this code. change AFTER **point = chart.series[0].points[pointIndex];** BEFORE **});**

```
if (thisChart === Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.hoverChartIndex]) {
    Highcharts.charts.forEach(function(chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[pointIndex];

        // CHANGE START
        if (point.y == null) {
            // set here your color for null values
            result +=
                '<span style="color:black' +
                '">●</span> ' +
                point.series.name +
                ": <b>" +
                point.y +
                "</b><br/>";
        } else {
          result +=
            '<span style="color:' +
            point.color +
            '">●</span> ' +
            point.series.name +
            ": <b>" +
            point.y +
            "</b><br/>";
        }
        // CHANGE END
    });

  } else {
    result =
      '<span style="color:' +
      this.color +
      '">●</span> ' +
      this.series.name +
      ": <b>" +
      this.y +
      "</b><br/>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added this functionality by defining the color point like this:

```
let color = point.y === null ? 'black' : point.color
```

and use this color variable in the result:

```
  result +=
    '<span style="color:' +
    color +
    '">●</span> ' +
    point.series.name +
    ": <b>" +
    point.y +
    "</b><br/>";
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7x1oc2pw/

Is that what you had in mind?